# SQL: Running total by record groups

Tags: sql, teradata

I'm trying to create a running total based on groups of records. My data looks like the below

```
Country | Genre | Month | Amt
A         X        1       5
A         X        2       3
B         X        1       8 
B         Y        1      10
A         X        1      12
```

I'd like to do a running sum on Amt grouped by unique occurences of Genre and Month for each Country. So my desired output is

```
Country | Genre | Month | Amt | RunAmt
A        X        1       5           5
A        X        2       3           3
B        X        1       8           8
B        Y        1      10         10
A        X        1      12         17
```

Since Genre = X and Month = 1 has occurred previously for country A.

My attempt has been `sum(amt) over (partition by country, genre, month order by month rows between unbounded preceding and current row)` but it seems to do a running sum over every row not for unique occurences by country. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Your attempt already returns the expected result (and both existing answers do exactly the same, if you add `rows...`). If this is not what you want you should include more data and an exact explanation for the correct result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculate a Running Total in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT *,
       Sum(amt)
         OVER(
           partition BY country, genre, month
           ORDER BY amt) as RunAmt
FROM  ( VALUES ('A','X',1,5),
               ('A','X',2,3),
               ('B','X',1,8),
               ('B','Y',1,10),
               ('A','X',1,12) )tc(Country, Genre, Month, Amt)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
select *, 
    sum(amt) over 
    ( 
        partition by country, Genre, month order by amt
    ) as RunAmt 
from TableName
```

Here is the [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/711e6/1) for you that I tried.